# Генерация проекта. Maven

Tags: maven

Пытаюсь сгенерировать проект Maven. Ввожу в командной строке команду `mvn archetype:generate`
В итоге выдает следующую ошибку:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.checkStarted (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.getService (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.getService (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.initialize (P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.initialize (PlexusLifecycleManager.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.activate (PlexusLifecycleManager.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler.schedule (BeanScheduler.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.manage (PlexusLifecycleManager.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBeanBinder.afterInjection (PlexusBeanBinder.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.notifyListeners (MembersInjectorImpl.java:131)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision (ConstructorInjector.java:125)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000 (ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call (ConstructorInjector.java:98)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct (ConstructorInjector.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:306)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTargetPlatformResolverFactory.lookupPlatformResolver (DefaultTargetPlatformResolverFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.setupProject (DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead (TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:70)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume (InternalSystemBundle.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch (Framework.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup (EclipseStarter.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.doStart (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.start (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.checkStarted (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.getService (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.getService (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.initialize (P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.initialize (PlexusLifecycleManager.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.activate (PlexusLifecycleManager.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler.schedule (BeanScheduler.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.manage (PlexusLifecycleManager.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBeanBinder.afterInjection (PlexusBeanBinder.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.notifyListeners (MembersInjectorImpl.java:131)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision (ConstructorInjector.java:125)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000 (ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call (ConstructorInjector.java:98)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct (ConstructorInjector.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:306)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTargetPlatformResolverFactory.lookupPlatformResolver (DefaultTargetPlatformResolverFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.setupProject (DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead (TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:70)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator (BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start (BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume (InternalSystemBundle.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch (Framework.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup (EclipseStarter.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.doStart (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.start (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.checkStarted (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.getService (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.getService (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.initialize (P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.initialize (PlexusLifecycleManager.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.activate (PlexusLifecycleManager.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler.schedule (BeanScheduler.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.manage (PlexusLifecycleManager.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBeanBinder.afterInjection (PlexusBeanBinder.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.notifyListeners (MembersInjectorImpl.java:131)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision (ConstructorInjector.java:125)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000 (ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call (ConstructorInjector.java:98)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct (ConstructorInjector.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:306)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTargetPlatformResolverFactory.lookupPlatformResolver (DefaultTargetPlatformResolverFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.setupProject (DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead (TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:70)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The System Bundle could not be resolved: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.checkSystemState (BaseStorage.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.getStateManager (BaseStorage.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.getState (BaseAdaptor.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.frameworkStart (BaseStorage.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.frameworkStart (BaseAdaptor.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start (SystemBundleActivator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run (BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator (BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start (BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume (InternalSystemBundle.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch (Framework.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup (EclipseStarter.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.doStart (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.start (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.checkStarted (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.getService (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.getService (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.initialize (P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.initialize (PlexusLifecycleManager.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.activate (PlexusLifecycleManager.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler.schedule (BeanScheduler.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.manage (PlexusLifecycleManager.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBeanBinder.afterInjection (PlexusBeanBinder.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.notifyListeners (MembersInjectorImpl.java:131)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision (ConstructorInjector.java:125)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000 (ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call (ConstructorInjector.java:98)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct (ConstructorInjector.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:306)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTargetPlatformResolverFactory.lookupPlatformResolver (DefaultTargetPlatformResolverFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.setupProject (DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead (TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:70)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:
```

Answer (score 0):

В ошибке упоминается `J2SE-1.5`, проверьте версию под которой запускаете, я надеюсь вы не на 5 java пишите до сих пор.

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java. вот ссылка на тот репозиторий, который я скачал и для которого использую Maven